# How to set checkbox to expand or collapse its items and itemchilds

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to build a simple menu where you can click on the parent check box it expands or collapses its children. I also have children of a parent that have grand children inside of them.  How can I set when you click on the parent checkboxes they expand and hide the children items inside them and when you click the parent

this is the final out come I want to achieve

[image]

my function to select or unselect

```
 selectUnselectAll(obj) {
    obj.isAllSelected = !obj.isAllSelected;
    // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
    for (let i = 0; i < obj.ParentChildchecklist.length; i++) {
      obj.ParentChildchecklist[i].isSelected = obj.isAllSelected;
      // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-for-of
      for (let j = 0; j < obj.ParentChildchecklist[i].choices.length; j++) {
        obj.ParentChildchecklist[i].choices[j].isSelected = obj.isAllSelected;
      }
    }
  }
```

this is my whole application

[Link to the app in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-evn45d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

this is what I have achieved so far
[image]

My dressing and bread lists doesn't collapse at all. How can I make the children also collapse?

Any help on how to achieve this appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `valueChanges` Observable of the parent controls and *ngIf it on the child controls container:

In TS:

```js
this.showBread$ = this.breadCtrl.valueChanges;
```

In HTML:

```html
<input type="checkbox" [formControl]="breadCtrl">
<div class="bread-container" *ngIf="showBread$ | async">
  <!-- children here -->
</div>
```

It means switching to reactive forms, but that's strongly recommended in 99% of cases anyway.

EDIT: You would then use `patchValue` on each control (or their containing FormGroup) as opposed to your current method of ticking the boxes (which currently doesn't use a very "Angular" approach).